# Cannot upload 'MOV' file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I was wondering if anyone experienced the same issue, when uploading a `.mov` apple quickTime file. I have made no changes to the php.ini file.

Here is the code:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file_box']['name'])) {
    echo nl2br ("No files where found to upload, skipping process. \n");
   } else {

  $file = $_FILES['file_box'];


  //File Info
  $file_name = $file['name'];
  $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
  $file_size = $file['size'];
  $file_error = $file['error'];



  //Find file extention

  $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
  $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

  $allowed = array('mp4', 'm4v', 'mov');

  if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
    if ($file_error === 0) {
      $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
      $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

      if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
        echo nl2br ("File Uploaded! \n");
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you upload a small .mov? PHP and most web servers limit post sizes. What error are you getting?

Comment: no error, it just says 'No files where found to upload, skipping process.', and is 11mb too big?

Comment: you mean you can upload other extensions but not `.mov`?

Comment: yeah, weird error right?

Comment: yeah it seems weird but i think your file may b has some problems, have you tried any other `.mov` file?

Comment: with a different file i get the same problem, makes me wonder if it is an error in the php.ini file?

Comment: yeah and i still get the error, all the files have been exported out of quicktime player on mac os sierra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue,

There was a problem in the PHP config file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is already very old issue but it so happen that I encounter this in my recent project. In my case its php config limit and I dont want to touch my php config so I put the following value in my htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
php_value post_max_size 300M
```

This maybe not the best solution but since my project is just for my own use so its sufficient for me.